# .NET: Which strategy is better for populating a gridview? using a Data Table and bind it or using a data reader?

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, binding, datatable

ASP.NET: Which strategy is better for populating a gridview? filling a Data Table and bind it or using a data reader ? Which one has a better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A datareader is always faster (since the datatable uses it to fill itself also), but it's trivial.. just use what'll be the fastest to develop.

Comment: @www.chrisvandesteeg.nl : thank you, but how do you know that data table uses it (data reader) to fill itself?